# Get the last modified file

Tags: batch-file

I'm doing a batch file and I want to get the last file copied to the directory. In this case, a `.cmd` file which is always generating a new one.

The first tentative I have made was using the `/T:W` thing and it's was working very nice; the problem is happening when the file name use two (or more) numbers.

```
for /f %%x in ('dir C:\foldercmd\*.cmd /B /T:W ') do set "cmdFile=%%x"
```

So the output i'm getting is:

```
C:\Users\foldercmd>set "cmdFile=cmdWork_1.cmd"
C:\Users\foldercmd>set "cmdFile=cmdWork_10.cmd"
C:\Users\foldercmd>set "cmdFile=cmdWork_11.cmd"
C:\Users\foldercmd>set "cmdFile=cmdWork_12.cmd"
C:\Users\foldercmd>set "cmdFile=cmdWork_2.cmd"
C:\Users\foldercmd>set "cmdFile=cmdWork_3.cmd"
C:\Users\foldercmd>set "cmdFile=cmdWork_4.cmd"
C:\Users\foldercmd>set "cmdFile=cmdWork_5.cmd"
C:\Users\foldercmd>set "cmdFile=cmdWork_6.cmd"
C:\Users\foldercmd>set "cmdFile=cmdWork_7.cmd"
C:\Users\foldercmd>set "cmdFile=cmdWork_8.cmd"
C:\Users\foldercmd>set "cmdFile=cmdWork_9.cmd"
```

And i want to get:

```
C:\Users\foldercmd>set "cmdFile=cmdWork_1.cmd"
C:\Users\foldercmd>set "cmdFile=cmdWork_2.cmd"
C:\Users\foldercmd>set "cmdFile=cmdWork_3.cmd"
[...]
C:\Users\foldercmd>set "cmdFile=cmdWork_11.cmd"
C:\Users\foldercmd>set "cmdFile=cmdWork_12.cmd"
```

Comment: Batch won't do that. But you can sort on time not name see `dir /?` and `/o`. Only Shellcmp functions understand numbers in strings. That is Explorer.

Comment: Your naming scheme would be better sortable using leading `0`s, i.e. `"cmdWork_01.cmd"`, `"cmdFile=cmdWork_10.cmd"`, `"cmdFile=cmdWork_11.cmd"`, `"cmdFile=cmdWork_12.cmd"`, `"cmdFile=cmdWork_02.cmd"`, `"cmdFile=cmdWork_03.cmd"`, `"cmdFile=cmdWork_04.cmd"`, `"cmdFile=cmdWork_05.cmd"`, `"cmdFile=cmdWork_06.cmd"`, `"cmdFile=cmdWork_07.cmd"`, `"cmdFile=cmdWork_08.cmd"` and `"cmdFile=cmdWork_09.cmd"`. Windows sorts alphabetically in characters order, not numerically.

Comment: Your issue is that `/Tx` sets the datetime field that would be reported (x=a:accessed, c:created, w: written(default)) You need to make `dir` sort the list - but remember that `copy` sets the time-last-written of the destination file to that of the source file.

Comment: Thanks @Compo, it's a nice alternative.

Comment: Try this: `dir /B /A:-D /O:D /T:W "C:\foldercmd\cmdWork_*.cmd"`. Anyway, you need to decide whether you want the files sorted by their names (`*_1.cmd`, `*_2.cmd`,...,`*_10.cmd`,...) or by their age (last mod. date/time); your question is not quite clear about that, and title and body do not really match...

Comment: This question is unclear, you say you want the latest file, then show expected result of multple files (not latest) but you also want them ordered by name?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard every week we have a new cmdfile and it just increment +1 to the name. I want to get, every final week, the latest file. In this case is cmdWork_12.cmd, next week will be cmdWork_13.cmd

Comment: ok, but then you only expect 1 single result right? Latest file?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard yap.

Comment: So have you tried/had a look at my answer I posted below?

Answer (score 1):

I am going to answer this question purely by the title. **Get last modified file**

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir "C:\foldercmd\*.cmd" /b /a-d /o-d') do set "cmdfile=%%i" & goto :end
:end
echo %cmdfile%
```

This will order the files `*.cmd` in order, latest files first, then only set the first file as latest and echo it. Once you have a new `.cmd` file added to that directory, it will then select the new one.. easy as that.

Answer (score 0):

According to `Dir /?` the `/O` switch allows you to sort. In case you want to do this, based on last modification date, you can use `D`, so you get:

```
Dir /OD
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

If you were unable to modify the process which is naming the files, and you wanted to still sort using the names, you may be able to leverage [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) from your [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```bat
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('PowerShell -NoP^
 "GCI "C:\foldercmd" -Fi "cmdWork_*.cmd"|Sort{If($_ -Match '(\d+)')"^
 "{[int]$Matches[1]}}|Select -Exp Name"')Do Set "cmdFile=%%A"
```

The above example loops through each file, `set`ting each in turn, until the last, but you could ask [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) to return only the last if you only wanted to:

```bat
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('PowerShell -NoP^
 "GCI "C:\foldercmd" -Fi "cmdWork_*.cmd"|Sort{If($_ -Match '(\d+)')"^
 "{[int]$Matches[1]}}|Select -Exp Name -L 1"')Do Set "cmdFile=%%A"
```

Answer (score 0):

Two pure batch solutions searching the highest number used.

1. using a counting loop

   ```
   :: Q:\Test\2019\04\29\SO_55899758.cmd
   @Echo off
   for /l %%L in (1,1,100) do if not exist "C:\foldercmd\cmdwork_%%L.cmd" (
       set /a "No=%%L-1"
       goto :Done
   )
   Echo Highest number is greater 100
   Goto :Eof
   :Done
   echo Highest used number is %No%
   pause
   ```
2. splitting the name at the underscore and comparing with the previous

   ```
   :: Q:\Test\2019\04\29\SO_55899758_2.cmd
   @Echo off & Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
   set "No=0"
   for /f "tokens=2 delims=_." %%L in ('
       dir /B "C:\foldercmd\cmdwork_*.cmd"
   ') do if %%L gtr !No! set "No=%%L"
   echo Highest used number is %No%
   pause
   ```